# How to specify a tag when running build pipeline?

Tags: azure-pipelines

Suppose we have a master branch, with tags like v1.0, v1.2, etc..
Do i just need to type `refs/tags/v1.0`? but i dont understand, how does it know what branch to look in then?
Or should it be like `master/refs/tags/v1.0`?

[image: ref]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For example, create a new branch test based of master->open branch test and add tag at the first commit, switch the branch to master, we will also see the same tag in the master.

In the Azure DevOps, Tags are created based on the commit id, and a commit or tag can belong more than one branches. Check this [ticket](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65709675/get-the-branch-name-from-tag-using-azure-devops-api/65713538#65713538).

We need enter `refs/tags/v1.0` instead of `master/refs/tags/v1.0` or select the tag in the tab page, check the pic below.

[image]

**Uodate1**

Check the gif, I add the tag test in the master branch, then switch to commit page, we could see the tag in the master branch.

Create branch **test** and switch to commit page, we could also see the tag in the **test** branch.

[image]

Result: The tag is based on **commit** instead of **branch**.

In the git, Tags are created based on the commit id, and a commit or tag can belong more than one branches. Let’s illustrate by below graph:

```
A---B---E---F master
     \     
      C---D   test
```

This is a branch structure with master and test branch. and both branch test and master have the commit B, when we create tag in the B commit, both branch **test** and **master** have the tag.

Then I run the pipeline via the tag

Run the pipeline via `master/refs/tags/test`

[image]

Run the pipeline via `refs/tags/test`

[image]

Comment: `create a new branch test based of master->open branch test and add tag at the first commit, switch the branch to master, we will also see the same tag in the master.` ohhh is that why i dont see any files in master branch on bitbucket? So in other words, tags would be based on a branch derived from master and master will have the tagged commits from that branch

Comment: Hi @Cataster, I have updated the answer, please check the update1.

Comment: Thank you Vito! We basically want to deploy ”releases” to production in the pipeline, instead of deploying changes from dev to master branch directly, so that this,way theres always a ”working released version we can rollback to if needed. That's why I was curious about the tags. I appreciate the gif!

Comment: Hi @Cataster, You are welcome, If this answer is helpful, would you please accept it as the answer? So it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread. Thanks. Have a nice day. :)